# Red agleonema has yellowing leaves?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, leaves, indoors

[image]Some of the leaves have stared turning yellow and drooping. The soil is completely dry right now but I was afraid the yellowing was because of overwatering. Please help :)

Comment: Hi Natalie, welcome to the site.  Could you please upload a picture of your plant?  And, how much had you been watering the plant?

Comment: Hello-thanks, I’m trying to figure out how to add a picture.

Comment: Hi Mack, I have been watering about every three weeks.. when the soil gets to be dry on the top three inches of soil

Comment: Rainforest plants expect soil that is constantly moist. I'd be watering twice a week, when the very surface is drying out, not bone dry. I have not succeeded in rooting Aglaonema in water, as I had expected to.

Answer (score 1):

The watering regime of about every three weeks sounds good.  There is no sign of the common pests like mealybug.  I notice the plant is in a large pot with not a lot of foliage so the soil may not be drying out enough.  I am going to assume that is has enough drainage at the bottom.

Here is my suggestion to help the plant.

- move to a higher light location
- this plant buds out from stems readily.  Cut all the foliage off leaving two or three inches of stem and root the cuttings in water.  When they have enough roots pot them in with the old plant.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have  just recently moved this to a brighter light location so hopefully that helps. 
Cutting makes me nervous as I’m not sure exactly where to cut..do I cut right at the base of each leaf and put them in water?

Comment: Also, should I wait until spring to cut the stem or is it okay to cut them now?

Comment: @Natalie  Aglo's are tough plants.  You can cut it now by cutting the stem one or two inches up from the soil. Put the stem and attached leaves in water and they will root.

Comment: Thanks so much! This was very helpful